# I'm an idiot and pulled up abestos vinyl flooring

Tags: asbestos

Don't be like me. 70s house, removed carpet to find two layers of vinyl flooring underneath. In pretty rough shape, holes, cracks, bends, etc. Decided to remove it prior to putting down new LVP. About halfway through, we hung plastic sheeting up to separate the area from the rest of the house due to the dust. Never ran the hvac but there was definitely some dust kick up before we put the plastic up.

Didn't realize until the end of the removal that the possibility of asbestos could be an issue. Sure enough, sent in two samples and there's asbestos.

Sample 1 was both layers of vinyl flooring, of which both had asbestos, 20% Chrysotile.

Sample 2 was the mastic between the vinyl and concrete subfloor, no asbestos.

So as it stands.....

99% of the vinyl flooring is out. Half the floor is covered somewhat by paper backing and there's white mastic here and there. Aside from a time machine to fix our stupidity, what can we do moving forward?

- Wet it all down, wear masks and scrape the remainder of the paper and mastic off the concrete. Then use some cleaning product on the concrete and walls and a run a filter in the room. Then a good thorough clean of the rest of the house where some of the dust may have migrated to.
- Call an abatement company to come clean the remainder. I'm guessing this would go into pretty expensive territory and we would have to move out of our house during?
- Lay down new LVP to encapsulate whatever is left.
- Other ideas?

Appreciate any guidance, thanks.

Comment: First idea probably the best for you.  Asbestos is usually the amount of time(maybe years) and amount breath in.  If most of the floor came out in chunks instead of sanding it away it is a lot better for you.   Knowing it is asbestos now, might make very hard to get rid of now.  Will need special bags and places to remove it, you can't dumb it in the garbage now.

Comment: the clock is ticking

Comment: Would probably let your doctor know you may have been exposed to some asbestos,next time you talk to them, so they are aware of the potential, and can place a note in your records.

Comment: Depending on your jurisdiction, calling a licenced asbestos removal company is probably your only legal move.  Dealing with it yourself could land you in a lot of trouble.

Comment: @crip659  Thanks.  We had to cut the vinyl with a knife and then ripped it up in rows.  It did get decently dusty but that appeared to mostly due to the mastic, which tested positive.  With the vinyl, is the asbestos usually within the vinyl material itself or the paper backing?

Comment: @Chenmunka Thanks, yeah we'll give a few companies a call either way to see where we stand.

Comment: Probably in the vinyl.  It is the free floating dust that does the nasty, sanding it is much more dangerous than ripping it up in pieces.  Your building department should give proper advice on what you can do yourself.

Comment: @crip659  Thanks.  Made a typo in my last response, the mastic tested negative, only the vinyl tested positive.